# Quoting problems using jq in bash to replace json property with backslashes in content

Tags: json, bash, kubernetes, jq

I'm working with a json document where the property keys are filenames, and the values are the intended content of those files, where the files are mostly Java properties files.

I'm writing a Bash script that produces a modified json, where the change is the text in a single "line" of the content of one of the json properties.  This is essentially changing the value of a single property in the embedded Java properties file.

If it matters, the json document is a kubernetes configmap, but that doesn't matter for the problem I'm having.

The process is essentially this:

```
augfile=$(cat $outfile | sed -e "s/${property}[     ]*=.*$/${property}=${newValue}/")
kubectl get configmap $configmap -o json | jq ".data[\"$filename\"] = \"$augfile\"" | kubectl replace $configmap -f -
```

What I see in the output is this:

```
+ kubectlidp dev2 get configmap onemapms-green-configs -o json
+ jq '.data["application.properties"] = "...
...
listprop    =\
abc=def,\
ghi=jkl,\
mno=pqr
..."'
+ kubectl replace <configmapname> -f -
jq: error: Invalid escape at line 2, column 1 (while parsing '"\
"') at <top-level>, line 129:
listprop    =\
```

It's clear that I have to modify the way I specify the "$augfile" value, but I'm lost in the quotes there.

Comment: In JSON a newline should be `\n`, not an escaped newline.

Comment: I don't know how that helps me fix this.

Comment: In accordance with the [mcve] guidelines, it might be a good idea to include some representative JSON, that is, sufficient to exhibit the problem.

Comment: @Barmar does remind me of the fact that I have to figure out how to convert the value in $augfile to the form that is legal in a json property value, which would convert "\" to "\\\n". Perhaps that's all I have to do.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr, ...for a standalone reproducer showing peak's answer in action, see https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/864775262f2a433c7918e6c91dd876c5; as you can see, the data being substituted doesn't need to contain any literal quotes or escapes at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you can sometimes get away with using shell string interpolation to "construct" the jq program, it's almost always better to pass in the shell values using the jq command-line options --arg and/or --argjson, e.g. in your case (assuming your shell allows this style of quoting):

```
 jq --arg filename "$filename" --arg augfile "$augfile" '
   .data[$filename] = $augfile'
```

Comment: His shell is `bash`, according to the tags. Why wouldn't it allow this style of quoting?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The problem isn't with literal quotes, it's with literal newlines.

Comment: But I think this answer handles any special characters, since it's not doing any interpolation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not sure what you're trying to say. My comment was just addressing the parenthetical "assuming your shell allows this style of quoting".

Comment: Ahh; I missed that context. Violent agreement it is.

Comment: This looks very promising. I'll test it as soon as I fix a different problem, trying to restore my k8s configmap from backup.

Comment: All working.  For others, it's important to have the final expression single-quoted, instead of double-quoted, because otherwise the shell will do the replacement, instead of jq.